# Magento2 : Display percentage of discount on product list and view page

Tags: magento2, price, discount, sale-price

I want to display discount in percentage format on **product list** and **product view page** as like below

```
30% Discount
```

How I can achieve this task in proper Magento-2 way.

Code should be define in any one place and use it in anywhere.

thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried my solution?

Comment: I have completed, check my below answer for display it any list.

Comment: Check out this free extension https://magecomp.com/magento-2-discount-percentage.html

Answer (score 5):

Try this in `design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

```
<?php
    $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
    $specialPriceFromDate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
    $specialPriceToDate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();    
    $today = time();
    $price = $_product->getPrice();
    if($price){
        $sale = round((($price-$specialprice)/$price)*100);
    }
    if ($specialprice) {
        if ($today >= strtotime($specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime($specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)) { ?>
            <div class="label-product label-sale">
                <span class="sale-product-icon">
                    <?php if($sale) { echo $sale.'%'; } else {echo __('Sale');} ?>
                </span>
            </div>
        <?php }
    }
?>
```

The same way you can do it from product page.

Answer (score 4):

I have completed it by bellow code for display in any product list.

Create below helper function in your module

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Helper;


class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    public function DisplayDiscountLabel($_product)
    {
        $originalPrice = $_product->getPrice();
        $finalPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();

        $percentage = 0;
        if ($originalPrice > $finalPrice) {
            $percentage = number_format(($originalPrice - $finalPrice) * 100 / $originalPrice,0);
        }

        if ($percentage) {
            return $percentage."% DISCOUNT";
        }

    }
}
```

You can call it any product list like below code

```
<?php echo $this->helper('VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Data')->DisplayDiscountLabel($_product); ?>
```

Comment: You did what I advised you with only a difference: you implemented _DisplayDiscountLabel_ method in **helper** instead of in **block**.. that it should be the right place.

Comment: Thanks Suresh, Above code will not work when catalog price rule applied on the product. Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

If you set discounts via Catalog Price Rules, you'll get wrong final prices by methods like

```
$finalPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
// or
$specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
```

It works only for special prices set in products.
But for catalog price rules $finalPrice will be equal $originalPrice

This works:

```
$finalPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to overwrite

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php

file and

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

template into your module.

In the first file you should add and implements your method to calculate product discount percentage; in the second one (template) you should call the method.

Comment: How to ovveride file 'FinalPriceBox.php'?

Comment: this work only simple product type only