# Magento 2.2.4 configurable catalog price rule

Tags: configurable-product, catalog-price-rules, magento2.2.4, price-rules, associated-products

I have a configurable product with 4 associated products. Each associated product has a different price (3.20€, 8.80€, 20€, 40€). 
I have also set a catalog price rule of 20% discount on all products of a specific category, in which this product belongs to. This means that the prices of the associated products should now be (2.56, 7.04, 16 and 32 respectively)

My problem is that in product view page, the displayed price is 3.20€. If I select the cheapest option and add it to cart, the value that is being added is the correct one (2.56€). How can i get the discounted price on product view page?

Comment: Refer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155684/magento2-display-percentage-of-discount-on-product-list-and-view-page

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Thanks for the reply, this wasn't what i was asking for, anyway it was an indexing problem which i've solved.